# amazon s3 pre signed urls should be resigning with new access key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have files that are pre signed with old access key. Now the access key is inacitvated. Need to sign the old pre signed files with new access key. Please suggest..

Answer (score 0):

As a work around i have resigned the old pre-signed url's with new access key through java.